# HVAC JWT authentication

Tags: python, authentication, jwt

I am trying to use HVAC in order to authenicate to a Hashicorp Vault using JWT.
To do this I wanted to use the function from the HVAC documentation:

```
import hvac
client = hvac.Client()

response = client.auth.jwt.jwt_login(
    role=role_name,
    jwt=generate_token_response['data']['token'],
)
```

I generated a role for a JWT Rule in Hashicorp.
However the `generate_token_response` is nowhere to find as a function and I am not sure how I can generate it. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you!

Until now I tried different versions of possible jwt but nothing matched.

Answer (score 0):

The jwt parameter is the actual jwt string from whatever (auth provider) generates for you. There is no specific function like in the example.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here a quick python function i made to connect to Vault using a JWT token

```
import hvac
from hvac.api.auth_methods import JWT

# auth_path is the authentication path configured of your JWT authentication method
def connect_to_vault_jwt(vault_url, jwt, role, auth_path, namespace):
    client = hvac.Client(url=vault_url, namespace=namespace)
    JWT(client.adapter).jwt_login(role=role, jwt=jwt, path=auth_path)
    return client
```

namespace value is available if you are using Vault Enterprise